# Symfony2 - redirect /web directory to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, symfony, url-rewriting

I've got a duplicate content problem with my Symfony2 projet. The following urls gives the same content :

`www.mywebsite.com/web/page` and `www.mywebsite.com/page`

Here is the content of my `/.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And the content of my `/web/.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I would like to redirect any url starting with `/web` to `/` but I can't manage to do it. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Can someone explain me why this question were closed as "off topic" in order to know it for the next time ?

Comment: As said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so), questions related to htaccess are not necessarly off topic on SO. I then voted to reopen it as it has not even been moved to another site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your web directory (the `/web/.htaccess` file), add these rules right beneath the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects all direct access to the web directory to the root.